# What dark green LEGO car is this?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, vehicle

[image: Image of green LEGO car or car base]

Who knows what set this dark green LEGO one piece car unit is from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's from [MCDR4-1 Circuit Star](https://brickset.com/sets/MCDR4-1/Circuit-Star), a McDonald's promotional set from 2009:

You can clearly see the wavy white and yellow lines on the side stickers.

[image: MCDR4-1 Circuit Star package]

Comment: I was soo close! I was just about to answer but you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry I have more mystery pieces to come! :)